# Extract data from text file to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a data extraction project. The program will prompt user to enter the number of text files they want to extract. Afterwards, the user will select the files they want. However, the data extracted is only based on the first text file selected. How do I go about solving this issue.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fileStringBasic As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
    k = InputBox("Give me some input")

    For i = 1 To k
        fileStringBasic = Application.GetOpenFilename()

        If fileStringBasic <> "False" Then
            Open fileStringBasic For Input As #iFile
            Do Until EOF(iFile)
                Line Input #iFile, textline
                Text = Text & textline
            Loop

            Close #iFile
            pos1 = InStr(Text, "Datalog report")
            pos2 = InStr(Text, "BOARD PN")
            pos3 = InStr(Text, "BOARD SN")
            pos4 = InStr(Text, "TESTER")
            pos5 = InStr(Text, "DEVICE")
            pos6 = InStr(Text, "USER NAME")
            Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos1 + 18, 11)
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos2 + 18, 10)
            Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos3 + 18, 8)
            Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos4 + 18, 9)
            Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos5 + 18, 11)
            Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Mid(Text, pos6 + 18, 11)
        End If
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to clear the variable text at beginning of the loop

```
For i = 1 To k
    Text = ""
    fileStringBasic = Application.GetOpenFilename()
```

Comment: Hi, patel thank you so much for the help. The program works perfectly now!